# fail to save model on local on spark

Tags: java, apache, scala, maven, spark-streaming

I am a new user of spark. 
today when I am  trying to save my trained model 
there's the error log showing...

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:334)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.impl.GLMClassificationModel$SaveLoadV1_0$.save(GLMClassificationModel.scala:65)
>     at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMModel.save(SVM.scala:84)
>     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MLproject$.main(:63)
>     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:46)
>     at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:51)
>     at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:53)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:55)   at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:57)    at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:59)     at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:61)  at
>   $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:63)   at $iwC$$iwC.(:65)
>     at $iwC.(:67)    at (:69)     at
>   .(:73)     at .()     at
>   .(:7)  at .()     at $print()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)   at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
>     at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)  at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
>   by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.spark.util.SerializableConfiguration cannot be cast to [B
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1922)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
>     ... 68 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.spark.util.SerializableConfiguration cannot be cast to [B
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

HERE'S THE KEY PARK OF MY CODE:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("BigData_Project").setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.memory", "8g").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true"))

val (trainData, validationData, testData) = PrepareData(sc)

trainData.persist(); validationData.persist(); testData.persist()

val model = trainEvaluate(trainData, validationData)

val RMSE = evaluateModel(model, testData)

model.save(sc,"MYPATH")
```

Thank you everyone very much

Comment: Is the snippet you pasted the 65 code line? `GLMClassificationModel.scala:65`

Comment: Also, past the part where you have this "[B" (if it is yours) java.lang.ClassCastException: `org.apache.spark.util.SerializableConfiguration cannot be cast to [B at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62) `